# Does Vishnu serve & worship Shiva only using the Agamas?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, worship, shiva-lingam, skanda-purana

After Shiva's complete supremacy was established during the *Fiery Linga incident* shortly after creation, Shiva instructed Vishnu & Brahma to worship him using the Agamas and they obeyed well. From [Skanda Purana 1.3b.16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370669.html) :-

> Śrī Śiva/Mahādeva said: Remember me, your sire ...  O gentle ones, what is proper has been spoken (i.e. asked by you). It has been desired by me (to say) also. You two deserve to worship me **by the method described in the Kāmika (Āgama).**

[image]

> Nandīśa said: **Viṣṇu and Brahmā wore matted hair and applied sacred ash over their bodies** ... Conversant with the esoteric doctrines of **all the Āgamas, they duly performed all the rites**

> Thus Brahmā and Viṣṇu propitiated Aruṇa-Śaṅkara for SIXTEEN THOUSAND YEARS and attained Śivajñāna.

Are there other methods used by Vishnu? Did Lord Raam also worship Shiva as per Agamas?